# in meteor apps, why do some external scripts need to be placed in a client/ subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I place the Mousetrap javascript file (http://craig.is/killing/mice) in my Meteor app's main directory, I get the following error:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

app/mousetrap.js:711
    _addEvent(document, 'keypress', _handleKey);
              ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at app/mousetrap.js:711:15
    at app/mousetrap.js:813:4
    at /Users/Suchow/Desktop/Collective/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:107:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Suchow/Desktop/Collective/.meteor/local/build/server/underscore.js:76:11)
    at run (/Users/Suchow/Desktop/Collective/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:93:7)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

The error goes away when the Mousetrap file is placed in a client/ subdirectory. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because server side doesn't have dom.
if u put it in root, it has been loaded in both server and client side.

lib like sugarjs, momentjs can work both side.

Answer (score 1):

In Meteor 1.0, when creating a package, the way to force Meteor to load 3rd party libraries only on the client side is to explicitly pass the `client` parameter to `api.addFiles` in your `package.js` file

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.addFiles('lib/thirdpartylibrary.js', 'client');
}
```